# How to unsupport iPhone X?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x

When I used Xcode 8, my app does not support iPhone X. And when the app is used with iPhone X, black margins are shown on the top and bottom of the app screen.

But after updating Xcode to 9, my app was automatically support iPhone X and now the app is shown fullscreen without the black margins on iPhone X simulator.

I don't want to support iPhone X yet because almost no one uses iPhone X.
But I can't find the way to disable iPhone X support on Xcode.

Does anyone know how to unsupport iPhone X?

Comment: You can't. Apple will ask every APP support iPhone X soon.

Comment: Source for "almost no one uses the iPhone X"?

Comment: If no one is using your app in iPhone X, why do you worry about unsupporting it? Since no one is using it, you can just leave black margins, nobody will notice

Comment: @BallpointBen I only saw one person who uses iPhone X by now since it released. Everyone uses 5S, SE, or non-plus version of 6/7/8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per apple document All new iOS apps and updates for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

You can check Link for official document
https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

You can use Safe area layout guide to make your app compatible to iPhone x

Comment: Thanks! I decided to support iPhone X.